# Use "read" in Bash script with a standard answer

Tags: bash-scripting

How can I use `read` with something as standard response, which the user can change though? (a default answer)

Answer (score 14):

*bash version 4+*

You would write this:

```
read -p "enter a value: " -i default -e answer
echo "you answered: $answer"
```

- `-i default` specifies the default answer.
- `-e` enables interactive (editing) mode for `read`. Without this option the default answer does not work.

---

*bash version < 4*
(macos has bash 3.x)

So, can't *edit* the default value with bash 3.2. You could do this:

```
default="the default value"
read -p "your answer [default=$default] " answer
: ${answer:=$default}
echo "you answered: $answer"
```

This uses the default value if the user enters nothing (empty string)

Comment: -bash: read: -i: invalid option
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]

Comment: Your version of bash? Are you using bash or /bin/sh ?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

Comment: The missing `-e` was the issue in my case. Thanks for pointing this out. It is not clearly stated in `help read`.

Comment: Tested on `5.2.21(1)-release`, no longer works.

Comment: Works fine with 5.2.26(1)-release. @what, what about it didn't work like you expected.

Answer (score -1):

Reference [read - Read a line from standard input](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html):

> This is a BASH shell builtin.
>
> One line is read from the standard input, and the first word is
>   assigned to the first name, the second word to the second name, and so
>   on, with leftover words and their intervening separators assigned to
>   the last name.
>
> If there are fewer words read from the standard input than names, the
>   remaining names are assigned empty values.
>
> The characters in the value of the IFS variable are used to split the
>   line into words.
>
> The backslash character `\' may be used to remove any special meaning
>   for the next character read and for line continuation.
>
> If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable
>   REPLY. The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered or
>   read times out.
>
> **Examples**

```
#!/bin/bash
read var_year
echo "The year is: $var_year"

echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read var_name
echo "Your name is: $var_name"
```